# When I'm trying to insert the image in the database, it just shows me the path only, e.g. 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images'

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8, crud

I'm new to Laravel 8 and I'm trying to insert the data with an image, so when I try to insert the data it just shows me the inserted data and image path only. How can I solve this?

#### File *RestaurantController.php*

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Restaurant;

    class RestaurantController extends Controller
    {
        function add(Request $request)
        {
            $resto = new Restaurant;
            $resto->name = $request->input('name');
            $resto->email = $request->input('email');
            $resto->address = $request->input('address');
            $resto->create_at = $request->input('create_at');
            $resto->uploaded_at = $request->input('uploaded_at');
            $resto->image = $request->input('image');
            // $resto->image = $request->file('image')->store('images');

            if($request->hasFile('image'))
            {
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path('/images'), $image_name);

                $image_path = "/images/" . $image_name;
            }

            $resto->save();
            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Client entered successfully');
            return redirect('list');
        }
    }
```

#### File *add.blade.php*

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                   placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="create_at">Create At Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="create_at" class="form-control" id="create_at">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="uploaded_at">Uploaded At Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="uploaded_at" class="form-control" id="uploaded_at">
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="image">
        </div>

        <button type="Submit" clas="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
@stop
```

#### File web.php

```
Route::get('/', [RestaurantController::class, 'index']);
Route::view('/add', 'add');
Route::post('/add', [RestaurantController::class, 'add'])->name('add');
```

I got `<img src=http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images alt="image" height="50" width="50" >` and what I want is [http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/`my_image_name`](http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/%60my_image_name%60)

When I perform `return $request->all();`, it shows me

> {"_token":"ExiC1hv4sX3qrz6ZcQJJNfIL6bjblw938hfRkG8J","name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com","address":"testing address","create_at":"2022-05-30","uploaded_at":"2022-06-01","image":{}}

as a output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {

    $file = $request->file('image');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/images';
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72558286/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `store()` method.

```php
...

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->image->store('image'); // See store()
}

$restro->image = $image;
$restro->save();
```

Inside the blade template, you can retrieve the stored file like this:

```html
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $restro->image) }}" />
```

Make sure you have created the symbolic link of your storage folder in your public folder. If you haven't, you can create it by this artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```